# Unhandled 'error' event when run npm install

Tags: npm, jhipster

When I run mvnw -Pdev,webpack command, I got this error. I will appreciate if anyone could help me.

--- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) @ demoapp ---

```
Running 'npm install' in C:\Users\pc\demoapp
> demoapp@0.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\pc\demoapp
> webdriver-manager update --gecko false

 [09:55:46] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\pc\demoapp\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
 [09:55:46] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\pc\demoapp\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
 events.js:183
       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
       ^

 Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:622:25)
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! demoapp@0.0.0 postinstall: `webdriver-manager update --gecko false`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the demoapp@0.0.0 postinstall script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-16T06_55_48_437Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same symptoms because of an inconsistent `node_modules/` state.
Deleting `node_modules/` and running `npm install --verbose` solved my issue. Even despite the `--verbose` flags, the installation process may not show progress for four and more minutes. Checking for a changing directory size of `node_modules/` regularly calmed me down and let me know the installation kept going on.

Answer (score 0):

When using Windows 10 Powershell, the solution to this for me was to run Powershell as Administrator. 
Prior to that, I tried deleting `nodes_modules/` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53558340/1207532 but that didn't make any difference for me.